PgVector Active Record support
I was successfully added a vector field on my database
create_table :scraped_documents do |t|
    t.references :client, null: false, foreign_key: true
    t.column     :embedding, :vector, limit: 1536
    t.text       :content
    t.timestamps
 end

Now when I check the Model I get the following
ScrapedDocument.first
unknown OID 42268: failed to recognize type of 'embedding'. It will be treated as String.

How can I make the ActiveRecord to understand the vector column in order to do similarity search to my model?

It seems that this is giving different OID,
postgres-# SELECT oid, typname
postgres-# FROM pg_type
postgres-# WHERE typname = 'vector';
Where does the ActiveRecord is picking the OID from?
